# .net command list package --format json in azure pipeline

Tags: .net, azure, nuget, devops, pipeline

I would like to run the following dotnet command on a hosted Azure pipeline to generate a nuget package list:

`dotnet list package --format json --include-transitive > /home/vsts/work/1/a/depts.json`

However, the command is not found:

```
Possible reasons are:
  * You misspelled a built-in dotnet command.
  * You wanted to run a .NET program, but dotnet-list package --format json --include-transitive > /home/vsts/work/1/a/depts.json is not present.
  * You wanted to run a global tool, but an executable prefixed with dotnet with that name could not be found in the PATH.
```

If I understand the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package) correctly, then I need.net core 3.1 or later versions. In the pipeline the version 2.221.0 is used. That's why I tried to install version 3.1.31. However, that doesn't work either.

Here is my pipeline:

```yaml
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

# install .net core sdk 6 for restore
steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core sdk'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'sdk'
    version: '6.0.x'
    includePreviewVersions: true

# restore solution
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    projects: '**/*.sln'
    feedsToUse: 'config'
    nugetConfigPath: 'nuget.config'
    externalFeedCredentials: 'TelerikFeed'
  displayName: Restore nuget packages

# install .net core runtime
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .NET Core runtime'
  inputs:
    packageType: 'runtime'
    version: '3.x'
    installationPath: $(Agent.ToolsDirectory)/dotnet

# execute list package command
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'custom'
    custom: 'list package --format json --include-transitive > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/depts.json'

# also not working
- task: Bash@3
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      dotnet list package --format json --include-transitive > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/depts.json

# publish file
- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    ArtifactName: 'drop'
    publishLocation: 'Container'
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong or if my scenario is even possible?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The top of [the docs for `dotnet list package`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-list-package) says it's available in .NET Core 3.1. However, that just refers to `dotnet list package` generally. If you scroll down to where `--format` is documented, it says:

> Available starting in .NET SDK 7.0.200.

Hence, you need to use the .NET 7 SDK.

Answer (score 0):

**`dotnet list package`** *--format and --json* does not work in the pipeline. Just use **`dotnet list package`** command in your pipeline like below:-

**I am using `asp.net` app with .net 6.0 and ran the build and publish pipeline like below:-**

```yaml
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - main

jobs:
- job: Build
  displayName: 'Build and Publish'
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'
  steps:
  - task: UseDotNet@2
    displayName: 'Install .NET Core SDK'
    inputs:
      version: '6.x'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Restore Dependencies'
    inputs:
      command: 'restore'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Build Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'build'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      arguments: '--configuration Release'

  - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
    displayName: 'Publish Project'
    inputs:
      command: 'publish'
      projects: '**/*.csproj'
      publishWebProjects: true
      arguments: '--configuration Release --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      zipAfterPublish: true

  - script: |
      export PATH="$PATH:/usr/share/dotnet"
      dotnet list package > $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/depts.json 
    displayName: 'Run dotnet list package'
      
  - task: PublishPipelineArtifact@1
    displayName: 'Publish Artifacts'
    inputs:
      targetPath: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
      artifactName: 'publishedApp'
      publishLocation: 'pipeline'
```

**OR**

```yaml
  - script: |
      export PATH="$PATH:/usr/share/dotnet"
      dotnet list package 
    displayName: 'Run dotnet list package'
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]